# Что делает SchemaType.Mapped?

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

Подскажите, пожалуйста,  что означет Mapped в данной строке

```
adapter.FillSchema(customers, SchemaType.Mapped);
```

посе ответа Alexander Petrov

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Mapped - 2 - 
Apply any existing table mappings to the incoming schema. Configure the DataSet with the transformed schema.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.schematype?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Вы в Блокноте код пишете? Или всё-таки в IDE? Любой продвинутый редактор выдаёт подсказку, просто прочитайте её. В крайнем случае смотрите документацию: [SchemaType Enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.schematype)

Comment: Только вот одно не понятно 1) в каком смысле употребляется "сопоставление таблиц" 2)и что это в принципе значит 3)Что называется входящей схемой. 4) о каком DataSet идет речь?

Comment: У датаадаптера можно настроить [маппинг](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapter-datatable-and-datacolumn-mappings). Параметр, про который вы спрашиваете, указывает, будет применяться этот маппинг или нет.

Comment: Можно поподробнее